# Worms Reloaded - Awards

Tags: worms-reloaded

When I play `Worms Reloaded` game, when the game ends, the statistics mentions lots of awards like `Lemming award` and the `Cockroach award`. Is there a place to look up the meaning of various awards?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't see this on the Worms wikia site, and I see no other promising sites.  Most of them are self-explanatory though, and you can correlate it to what you did during the game.  Google is also helpful; a search turned up [this discussion about the Lemming award](http://www.gamespot.com/xbox360/strategy/worms/show_msgs.php?topic_id=m-1-41522454&pid=937709).